# Accessing ngForm which is inside ng-template from controller in angular 7

Tags: angular

I have a from inside ng-template. I would like to access it through my controller but i keep getting undefined. I have tested the same code and i can access it using @ViewChild if i don`t use ng-template.**However in my case i can not remove ng-template since it is part of a reusable modal component. I dont want to access it in the submit event, i need the access in *ngAfterViewInit***.
Thanks in advance.

```
<ng-template #template>
    <form #formAccessor="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(formAccessor)">
    </form>
</ng-template>
```

Inside my contoller

```
@ViewChild('formAccessor') ngForm:NgForm;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 console.log(this.ngForm); //Prints undefined
}
```

Comment: Do you have imported the ' FormsModule' in the AppModule or in some child of AppModule?

Comment: Yes it is included in AppModule @G.Vitelli

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the self reference to `ng-template` using `ngTemplateOutlet`, so that template gets activated and the content inside gets rendered.

html

```
<ng-template #template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template">
   <form #formAccessor="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(formAccessor)">
   </form>
</ng-template>
```

See this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-template-self?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Hello, the template is part of a pop up module component. When i do what you asked, it renders the contents of the popup immediately at the bottom of the page and breaks the behaviour

Comment: In that case, you cannot get the reference of a form. Because your popup is not yet loaded with the template, making it not accessible inside `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Please create a stackblitz example to demonstrate more on what you are doing.